# C# HttpRequest Attach Cookie to request

Tags: c#, cookies, httprequest

I want to send a cookie pulled from Google Chromes network F12 tab to preproduce hitting the UI in an HTTP Request instead. However, I need to send the cookie that goes with the request. I can't seem to attach the cookie string to the request.

Capture from Google Chrome (f12)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOxwT.png

I need to attach that cookie to the request when I send it out.

```
        string cookie = "JSESSIONID_loginLite_remote=LJyKVLHGLZrpTq3npBWh8CJyqTND32HpscL48ndnSp0hj2g6yhcK!.....";
        string info = "RemoteObjectTimestamp=1430842283795&RemoteObjectRequest=%7B%22destination%22%...";

        char[] arr      = info.ToCharArray(); 
        byte[] data     = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(arr);

        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
        myHttpWebRequest.Method         = "POST";
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentType    = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength  = data.Length;

        //Data to write is not empty
        if (data.Length > 0)
        {
            Stream requestStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string pageContent = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

        myStreamReader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();
        myHttpWebResponse.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the lines:

```
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();  
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri("your domain here"), cookie);
```

Don`t forget replace "your domain here" to domain of target request Uri

Comment: I don't have a cookie. I have a giant string with multiple parts in it. So I need to convert the giant string into a cookie and then I can add it to the request.

Comment: Have you tried to put you giant string in "cookie" variable in my methow above? Is it a problem?